# How to model subjects and their previous required subjects using recursive lists in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want to model subjects and their previous required subjects using recursive lists in prolog. I want to build the following structure: When I ask for the previous subjects of a given subject I want the result to be a list of list, where each of those small lists has the name of the previous subject and the tail is a list of the previous subjects of that one.

previous_of_sub0 = [ [sub1, [previous_of_sub1 ] ], [sub2, [previous_of_sub2]], ...]

I'm new to prolog so I don't know if this is possible but I thought about using recursion because the previous_of_sub1 would have the same structure as the previous_of_sub0.

My main problem is that, since a subject can have many previous subjects, I can't divide it into head and tail just like that. The previous subjects should be at the same level.

I tried using findall/3 and trying to call the same predicate in the template but it doesn't work.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example using Prolog code, demonstrating what failure and success look like.